# Zend Layout headLink()

Tags: zend-framework, http-status-code-404

I have setup a layout using Zend, and when I use:

```
<?php echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet('/css/global.css'); ?>
```

the browser does not locate my css file. It is located in:

```
public/css/
```

My document route in my vHosts file is set to /public. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the full path the browser tries to load the file with?

Comment: When you write http://[your_page]/css/global.css in your browser, is it accessible?

Comment: Then this is not a ZF problem. There's something wrong with your vhost  or rewrite rules. Check your Apache error log for clues.

Answer (score 0):

try `<?php echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet('css/global.css'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/global.css')
```

You have to define the baseUrl so that it can find the path of the css

Comment: I don't seem to be getting any output for $this->baseUrl()

Comment: Where are you using this code ? , i should be used in view file. did you try **echo $this->baseUrl()** in view file.